# How to make notebook act like hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to connect my notebook (with Windows 7) to my PC (with Windows 10) so that my notebook would act like a hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical way would be to do it as follows:

Share a folder or drive, and access its share from the other computer.

Answer (score 3):

You cant.

Well *usually*.

If your notebook would act as a *device* rather than a *host* as a phone or tablet does or you had a mac that did target mode, and the other system was compatible with this (and this was done over firewire or thunderbolt, depending on the *vintage* of the system), you might.

An arbitrary PC and laptop can't do this.

If you don't want to use a file share as LPChip suggested, the only real way is to pop out the drive from the notebook and hook it up to the PC either directly or with a USB adaptor.